# How to install python 2.7.12 on SLES 11?

Tags: suse

I have gone through this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10940296/installing-python-2-7-on-sles-11
and followed the instructions as suggested. I have created the bash file and executed that bash file somewhere between I got the error. So that I have executed the command step by step it was installed successfully. But while execute python in terminal it still showing python 2.6.9 version. Please let me know any other alternative solution to install python 2.7.12 in SUSE Machine.

Comment: Did you prepend your `PATH` and `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` to the `bin` and `lib` directory of where you installed `python 2.7.12`?

Answer (score 0):

Your `/usr/bin/python` might be a symlink and might be pointing to `/usr/bin/python2.6` file. Change the symlink (`/usr/bin/python`) to point to your latest python in `/usr/bin`:

```
ln -sf /usr/bin/python2.7 /usr/bin/python
```